# Reading an Image and Copying it on a predefined directory

Tags: java, image, io

I've been  trying to save images in my package directory,  but  I encountered a problem which I don't  know how  to go upon it,  this is my code:

```
BufferedImage   bufim = new BufferedImage(500, 600,   BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB );
String dof = "C:/myimage.jpg";
File  file = new File( dof );
String myimageFormat = "jpg";
ImageIO.write( bufim , myimageFormat,  file );
```

so this creates the file but I get this :
[image]

instead of this: which is the original image.

[image]

and my theory  is that it relates to:

```
BufferedImage   bufim = new BufferedImage(500, 600,   >>> THIS <<<  );
                                                  which is int imageType
```

Comment: Your BufferedImage object isn't being used in your code snippet? Where and what is your "image" and "myImageFormat" objects?

Comment: You create a brand new 500x600 RGB image. Then you write it to file. Why do you expect the image to be anything but default all-black pixels?

Answer (score 0):

so my problem was that I forgot  to assign  the  `bufim = ImageIO.read(incommingFileDirectory);` so that the `bufim` could have the `Image`   I want.